# Quarkus 2.16 doesn't start Apache Camel Dev Console

Tags: quarkus

this question is referring to the Apache Camel Console, not the Quarkus Dev UI.
I'm trying to enable it in Quarkus 2.16 as suggested in https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-console.html by

0. Starting with a code-with-quarkus template.
1. Adding to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-console</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

2. Adding to application.properties
   `camel.main.dev-console-enabled = true`
3. Launching with mvnw quarkus:dev

Trying to use `curl http://localhost:9080/q/dev/memory` results in 404.
Trying to use a debugger to see the startup sequence, it feels like the issue is that this returns null in AbstractCamelContext:
`DevConsoleRegistry dcr = getExtension(DevConsoleRegistry.class);`

I can't find a reason why this class isn't available, and I can't seem to find a way to trace how/where this was supposed to be packaged into the the jar or jandex or whatever it is to load it. (I'm quite new to Quarkus) HealthCheckRegistry, which is referring to in the code just above does get loaded, but nothing seems to stand out to me to show me why HealthCheckRegistry works but DevConsoleRegistry.class doesn't.